# Why new Turtle shapes have odd orientation (not the one I defined)?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I want to create yet another clone of Pong with Python and Turtle. My goal is to let my pupils (that begin to code in Python) to practise a bit further.

I'd like to create a Turtle whose shape is an horizontal filled rectangle, like a stylized paddle. But when I create a shape I suppose to be convenient, I get a rotated (vertical) paddle instead of the horizontal one I hoped for.

Here is a code that demonstrates this odd behaviour.

```
from turtle import *

begin_poly()
fd(200)
left(90)
fd(40)
left(90)
fd(200)
left(90)
fd(40)
left(90)
end_poly()
shape = get_poly()
register_shape("drawn", shape)

polyNotOk = ( (0,0), (100, 0), (100, 20), (0, 20) ) 
register_shape("polyNotOk", polyNotOk)

polyOk = ( (0,0), (0, 100), (20, 100), (20, 0) ) 
register_shape("polyOk", polyOk)

t1 = Turtle(shape="drawn")
t2 = Turtle(shape="polyNotOk")
t3 = Turtle(shape="polyOk")

t1.color("black")
t2.color("red")
t3.color("blue")

t1.stamp()
t2.stamp()
t3.stamp()

t1.goto(100,200)
t2.goto(100,-50)
t3.goto(100,-150)

t1.forward(100)
t2.forward(100)
t3.forward(100)

mainloop()
```

So, as you can see if you run the code, the first drawing is OK, with an horizontal shape. But when I stamp the Turtle `t1`, the shape is vertical.

Same problem with the 2nd shape, defined through `polyNotOk` (with values for x and y coords which allow to get a horizontal paddle). I need to create a "vertical" poly to get a horizontal paddle.

So I'm able to find a workaround. Yet I'm still not satisfied with this solution, so I'm asking for brilliant explanations ;-) Thanks in advance.

Comment: The turtle shape is relative to the turtle's heading - and they face right, by default.  Try `t.setheading(90)` to make it face up, or `t.settiltangle(90)` to reorient the shape while still having the turtle face right.

Comment: OK, I tried with t2.tiltangle(90) - Python 3 oblige - and the shape is correctly oriented. I do know that turtles are facing right by default, but I found insane the behaviour of Turtle with the begin_poly() / end_poly() logic. It is completely unnatural - at least to me. The logic is not very clear either, with the "polygon definition approach"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope to illuminate this odd behavior, not defend it.  First thing to remember about drawn cursors is that where ever `(0, 0)` falls in your cursor drawing, that's the center point about which your cursor rotates and the pixel in your cursor that lands on any point you `goto()`.

Some insight might be found in the `shapesize()` method documentation:

```
shapesize(stretch_wid=None, stretch_len=None, outline=None)

stretch_wid is stretchfactor perpendicular to orientation
stretch_len is stretchfactor in direction of turtles orientation.
```

That is, if the cursor is in the default (East) orientation, this reverses the sense of X and Y.  I believe that's what you're seeing in your drawing.  The X plane is perpendicular to orientation (vertical) and the Y plane is in the direction of orientation (horizontal).  The opposite of what we normally expect.

This doesn't appear to be the fault of the `Shape()` class, but buried in the cursor logic.  It may be a historical artifact--if we change to `mode("logo")` and run your code, we get:

[image]

More what we might expect, given that "logo" mode's default orientation is North, and more consistent than before.

Regardless, I would make my paddles a different way.  Instead of a custom cursor, I'd use turtle's *square* cursor and reshape it as needed using `shapesize()`:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

screen = Screen()

t0 = Turtle("square")
t0.shapesize(20 / CURSOR_SIZE, 100 / CURSOR_SIZE)

t0.color("green")

screen.exitonclick()
```

Still rotated logic (not graphic) from what you might expect, but at least the documentation told us that.  But, what I *really* tend to do is make the paddle in the wrong orientation, and use `settiltangle()`, but not as a workaround as you did, but to make my paddle face in one direction, but move in the other:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

screen = Screen()

t0 = Turtle("triangle")
t0.shapesize(100 / CURSOR_SIZE, 20 / CURSOR_SIZE)
t0.settiltangle(90)
t0.penup()

t0.color("green")
t0.speed("slowest")  # for demonstration purposes

t0.forward(300)
t0.backward(600)
t0.forward(300)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Notice that I can use `forward(10)` and `backward(10)` to move my paddle and not have to do awful things like `t0.setx(t0.xcor() + 10)`.  Works great for Space Invader type games where the player faces upwards but moves sideways.